# FB graph API post to page feed does not display via APP_NAME

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im posting to a fb page using graph api. the query im using is /page_id/feed/ and message="my msg" as parameter. This works great with posting to profiles. And it even shows the via APP_NAME next to the status update.

I tried this with page id's. It does post the status but however doesn't show via APP_NAME. Is there a way to show the via APP_NAME when posting to pages?

Thanks

Comment: Facebook pages don't show the "via APP_NAME" part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FB API for pages does not allow this feature at the moment.